# How to extend wso2 identity-inbound-auth-cas to accept a wildcard url

Tags: wso2, cas

I am trying to make it possible that if i add a CAS URL in a service provider using the UI after installing the wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-auth-cas lets say "https://test.com" than anything that is more than the base url should be accepted and recognized example "https://test.com/login?next=/hello/" but currently using the latest version of the extention 2.0.2 it fails. with 500 error

I am running the wso2is 5.7.0 on linux debian stretch and i have installing the [cas extension](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-auth-cas/tree/v2.0.2) i have added an SP named test and the CAS URL inside it is lets say "https://test.com/" now in my application if the url i would access CAS from is the exact same one defined in the wso2is UI in the CAS URL it works fine. If it has 1 more character it won't work. I want to extend it to make it work for anything more than or equal the CAS URL defined in the wso2is UI.

I expected that after extending this if i defined a CAS URL with the value of "https://test.com/" and i try to access "https://test.com/?next=/hello/" it should still work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, CAS service URL is the identifier of the application that the client is trying to access. In almost all cases, this will be the URL of the application (https://[server-address]/cas-client-webapp/) and the server-address should always point to the location where this sample application (cas-client-webapp) is deployed.

Since you have used Service URL: https://test.com in the service provider configurations and tried to access the service "https://test.com/login?next=/hello/" and still you don't have any registered service provider in wso2 identity server with the URL: "https://test.com/login?next=/hello/", it returns the default service provider configurations.

You may extend the source code [1] and make necessary changes to get the base URL: "https://test.com/" from the inbound configurations to cater your requirements.

[1] https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-auth-cas

Comment: I have applied some changes to where you instructed me to do. The 500 error is gone but the CAS authentication is not happening. After logging in the CAS token is not validated correctly. I think i am missing something somewhere. Also i think the fix that needs to be done should be from the request part. I want to be able to modify the request SP url when the CAS workflow is started. I need to be able to use the advantages of having sp=<SP-CAS-url> in the url rather than sp=default. @Priya